# Convert byte array to PDF file?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, pdf

I make a RESTful call from my iOS app in order to retrieve a pdf file. This pdf file is in byte format.

I have found many articles on how to convert these bytes to an actual file in Objective-C; however, I need help in the Swift language.

There are other things that get returned with the RESTful call as well, not just the file bytes, so I am extracting the bytes from the other information that is returned in the call.

```
let fileBlob = json["fileBlob"] as! String 
var data: NSData = NSPropertyListSerialization.dataWithPropertyList(fileBlob, format: NSPropertyListFormat.BinaryFormat_v1_0, options: Int(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves.rawValue), error: nil)! 
let file = data.writeToFile("readingfile.pdf", atomically: false)
```

Above is the code that I am using to extract file bytes from what is returned and then write that file to my computer just to see if I can get the pdf to open.

These three lines create the file, but when I click on the file to open it, it says it couldn't be opened because it may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesnt recognize...

Comment: In order to understand better your question: What is your intention? Just storing the retrieved PDF-File? Or do you want to interpret/modify the content of it, i.e. scanning/streaming it byte per byte?

Comment: I would like to simply display the pdf to the screen.

Comment: How about cleaning up the comments and putting everything to the main question using [EDIT button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31117328/edit) and formatting properly? That's why your question got downvoted - it does not provide sufficient info.

Comment: @AveryCupples How did you convert byte array to pdf? i have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSURLSession to do it asynchronously:

```
func load(URL: NSURL) {
   let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
   let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
   let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: {
       (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if (error == nil) {
         // Success
         let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
         println("Success: \(statusCode)")
         println("File Size: \(data.length)")

         // Your file variable is data (see previous println with data.length as example)

      } else {
        // Failure
        println("Failure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
      }
   })
   task.resume()
}
```

And then you could call it this way:

```
if var URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.whatever.com/yourfile.pdf") {
   load(URL)
}
```

If you want to test in in a playground you need the following two statements in your playground code:

```
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Comment: My pdf is not stored as a file as you have shown in the example with yourfile.pdf at the end of the url. I make my GET request and part of what I get returned is a fileblob with the file as bytes.